# How can I click first channel in YouTube with python after searching one?

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, webdriver, click

I am trying to click the first YouTube channel on the top of the result page. My code is as follows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
!pip install webdriver-manager
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe')
keyword=['"K_Pop TV"']

for kk in keyword:
    driver.get("http://youtube.com")
    #input keyword
    driver.find_element_by_name("""search_query""").send_keys(kk)
    #search
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #click the first channel on result page
    driver.find_elements_by_id('avatar').click()
```

However, I kept showing the error of "'list' object has no attribute 'click'", which may mean that it couldn't find the element of the channel access. Would someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error `'list' object has no attribute 'click` is cause you are using `find_elements` that will return a list of web element.

A list in Python does not have a `.click()` method

use `find_element` instead which will return a single web element.

so make the below change in your existing code :

```
driver.find_element_by_id('avatar').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. However, I still get the error of  `Message: invalid argument: invalid locator` after I replaced `driver.find_elements_by_id('avatar').click() ` with  `driver.find_elements('div#avatar.style-scope.ytd-channel-renderer').click()`  .

Comment: that looks to be a css selector, `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div# and so on ').click(),`

Comment: Glad that it worked, kindly accept the answer, by clicking on the check mark which is right along with voting buttons . Thank you